# Some variables passing but others arent in an included php file

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a included file for storing variables that are to be changed later on through a panel.
I have a handful of variables that are passing perfectly fine in the same file and fashion as the others.

```
<?php

    include 'functions/dbfunctions.php';
    include 'functions/variables.php';

?>
```

So this is the include and the variable file is :

```
<?php
    
//Enables

$headEnable = getDb('boxes_enabled', 'box1_header');

//Box 1

$headTitle = getDb('boxes', 'box1_header');
$headDesc = getDb('boxes', 'box1_info');
$headPlay = getDb('boxes', 'box1_play');

//Cards

$cardTitleA = getDb('boxes', 'card1_title');
var_dump($cardTitleA);
$cardInfoA = getDb('boxes', 'card1_info');
var_dump($cardInfoA);
$cardTitleB = getDb('boxes', 'card2_title');
var_dump($cardTitleB);
$cardInfoB = getDb('boxes', 'card2_info');
var_dump($cardInfoB);
$cardTitleC = getDb('boxes', 'card3_title');
var_dump($cardTitleC);
$cardInfoC = getDb('boxes', 'card3_info');
var_dump($cardInfoC);
$cardTitleD = getDb('boxes', 'card4_title');
var_dump($cardTitleD);
$cardInfo = getDb('boxes', 'card4_info');
var_dump($cardInfoD);


?>
```

Now the Enable and Head variables work fine, they show and have no problem, but the Card variables just dont pass.

```
<?php if($headEnable == 1) { ?>
                <section id="banner">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2>Welcome to <?php echo $headTitle; ?></h2>
                        <p><?php echo $headDesc; ?></p>
                        <a href="playnow.php" class="button scrolly"><?php echo $headPlay; ?></a>
                    </div>
                </section>
            <?php } ?>
```

Works perfectly fine.

```
<div class="card">
                             <div class="card-horizontal">
                                <div class="img-square-wrapper">
                                    <img class="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x180" alt="Card image cap">
                                 </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $cardTitleA; ?></h4>
                                <p class="card-text"><?php echo $cardInfoA; ?></p>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

This pushes out :

> [24-Apr-2021 22:48:21 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: cardTitleA in /dev/index.php on line 38
> [24-Apr-2021 22:48:21 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: cardInfoA in /dev/index.php on line 39

Not sure why one is working but the others isnt.

Database function :

```
function getDb($table, $column){
        
        $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
        
        $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table;
        
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $final = $row[$column];
        }
        
        return $final;
        
    }
```

Comment: try removing your var_dumps, might be becauase of that

Comment: I put the var_dumps in after it not working, hoping that might do it.

Comment: About the only way that this isn't working is if you are assigning or trying to echo those vars in a function.

Comment: You could also simplify and improve your code performance, instead of making a request for each column, just do it all at once becuase you seem to be consulting the same table all time so..

Comment: Plus the logical reason it doesn't works, is because that column is empty on your database, or null and maybe that is casted into an undefined exception because of the way you coded ur getDb function